# magento 2: get verbose output from indexer

Tags: magento2, indexing, customer-grid

I am having an issue with the customer_grid indexer
`php bin/magento index:reindex customer_grid`

After running this command, the cli will wait indefinitely for the process to finish. I use `update indexer_state set status='invalid' where status =' working'` to reset the customer_grid index but then the same thing happens after running the command again.

Is there a way to have a more verbose output or debug log for this command that I can refer to figure out what is causing the indexer to fail?

Comment: Please run query in order `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` , `update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';`, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`

Comment: Applied the change, but did not solve the issue.  Do we know what files manage the customer_grid index?

Comment: See what error you have in var/log/exceptions.lo.g Something fails in customer grid and it must be a SQL query. If you have many customers than maybe you need to increase ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M'). You can add it in app/bootstrap.php (which is included by both index.php and bin/magento), directly in bin/magento or in a server configuration.

Comment: I ended up running the indexer as a background task `php bin/magento index:reindex customer_grid &` and ran app like top to prevent ssh timeout.  It took ~45min but the indexer completed.  It would be nice if the indexer had an output like static-content that prevented ssh from timing out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your logs, running this command below when you run the `php bin/magento index:reindex`

`tail -f var/log/debug.log`

Try to enable SQL logging if needed.

```
php bin/magento dev:query-log:enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use verbose option of magento command `php bin/magento index:reindex -vv customer_grid`

Comment: -v -vv -vvv does not output anything for the customer_grid